# Can't log user created with a seeder in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having an issue in Laravel 5 logging with a user created by a seeder. The user is correctly created with his role and permission, I just can't log him in. I think this might be because of the user token, but I have no idea how to fix that... Here is the seeder code :

```
if ($this->command->confirm('Do you wish to refresh migration before seeding, it will clear all old data ?')) {
        // Call the php artisan migrate:refresh
        $this->command->call('migrate:refresh');
        $this->command->warn("Data cleared, starting from blank database.");
    }

    //create a user
    $mainAdmin = User::create([
        'name' => 'Alex',
        'email' => 'someadress@example.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
    ]);

    //create a role of admin
    $admin = Role::create([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'display_name' => 'Admin',
        'description' => 'Only one and only admin',
    ]);

    //create a permission for role
    $manageUsers = Permission::create([
        'name' => 'manage-users-roles-and-permissions',
        'display_name' => 'Manage Users,Roles and Permissions',
        'description' => 'Can manage users,roles and permission"s',
    ]);

    //here attaching permission for admin role
    $admin->attachPermission($manageUsers);

    //here attaching role for user
    $mainAdmin->attachRole($admin);
```

Here is the login form, it's a standard laravel login form, didn't touch it.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

      @if ($errors->has('email'))
         <span class="help-block">
             <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
         </span>
      @endif
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

    @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
            </label>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
        </button>

       <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
          Forgot Your Password?
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope someone can help me figure out this issue I'm really stuck with it !

Comment: do u get any errors are u using password: 'password' ? Share the login form also!

Comment: yes i'm using everything correctly, it just says on the view the regular error, there is no match in credentials for the user and the password, just in case i created a user with the regular registration form and i could log in, so i looked in the database, the only differences between a regular user and the one that was created with the seeder was that the regular ones have a remember_token value and the seeded one does not. IF it's not that i'm lost

Comment: remember_token it's not supposed to be used to authenticate, it's used by the framework to help against "remember me" cookie hijacking.

Comment: i didn't touch that yet, it's just the way laravel handles the authentification... So maybe my problem is something completely different I dont really know and i'm still a starter on Laravel. Just in case, would you know how to set a remember_token value with the seeder ?

Comment: when I seed I keep remember_token null and it doesn't affect my login procedure. I suggest u to edit .enc database settings, change database and try to seed with a new database.

Comment: it didn't change a thing...

Comment: U are using user:create and decrypting the password on it, since default laravel user create will hash it once it seems u are hashing the password twice before inserting it on database so leave password=> 'password'  delete and run the seeding again.

Comment: Ow that was it !! Indeed, I already crypt the password in a function in the User model, thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U are using `user:create()` and hashing the password on it, since default Laravel `user:create()` will automatically hash it once it seems u are hashing the password twice before inserting it on database.

I suggest you to leave `password=> 'password'` delete and run the seeding again.

Comment: totally did the job, 1 upvote for you ! Thank you again !